# Limitation of JavaScript base form validation

Tags: javascript, validation

Does JavaScript's base form validation have limitations since we know that there is an option for a user to **shut off Javascript option** from the browser?

Is client side base form validation is an efficient way to validate forms in a web application?

Comment: well, a normal way is to validate on both the client and the server side. The server side validation is the only trusted one (JS deactivation/manipulation) and hence JS validation is only a "comfort" feature for the user. Your question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed, as @Stasik says: once on clientside for responsiveness and user experience, once more on serverside for iron-tight security.

Comment: The client side validation is only for UI, animation and optimization but you always have to check the data in server side.

Comment: Clients can do more than just "shut off javascript", they can send anything they feel like. Server validation isn't just nice to have, it's essential if you care what your server is processing.

Comment: Today most of the common application we use are one-page applications, which are perfectly driven by js. As efficiency is the concern, I  think it will require less number of steps on validating data on the client over the server.